# Returning a static CLOB from an Oracle Stored Function

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to return a long paragraph from an Oracle Stored Function. I can do this in SQL Server, but I am new to oracle. How do I return long texts, like a User Agreement long paragraphs.

Note that it is only static texts and requires no DMLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your text is going to be over 32767 characters, then you will want to use the `CLOB` datatype. The [DETERMINISTIC clause](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/DETERMINISTIC-clause.html#GUID-6AECC957-27CC-4334-9F43-0FBE88F92654) is added to help with performance since there is no queries in the function, just string concatenation.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION return_clob
    RETURN CLOB
    DETERMINISTIC
IS
    l_return_value   CLOB;
BEGIN
    l_return_value := 'Some text.';
    l_return_value := l_return_value || ' Some more text.';
    RETURN l_return_value;
END;
/
```

Comment: +1 for the DETERMINISTIC clause. I read about it after seeing your answer, and found out it's good use-case for  instances like mine.